# Combining GridView and TabView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

There is a tabview at bottom and by default tab I am displaying Activity having a grid view.
But I am not able to get gridview . Here is my following code

Layout for activity

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/image" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/clubchart"/>

<GridView android:id="@+id/grid" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in `Activity`

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: there is no error just it doesnt get visible..If i remove tabview then grid view is displayed

Comment: HI guys thnks for the support my problem is solved